# possible to calculate average

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have following sample database:

```
date               open_price       closed_price 

25/1/19.            6                 10
24/1/19             10               12
23/1/19              8                7
22/1/19             9                 4
21/1/19            4                  12
20/1/19              7                16
.....
```

so would be possible to use sql /mysql to create another column and calculate average open_price of every 3 days automatically with following display:

```
date               open_price       closed_price     avg(3)

25/1/19.            6                 10             8
24/1/19             10               12              9
23/1/19              8                7              7 
22/1/19             9                 4             7
21/1/19            4                  12
20/1/19              8                16
.....
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=445), not sure why your question got downvoted so quickly, maybe start with neater formatting.

Comment: thanks so much, i have been searching and searching and just couln't find tutorial for it, this is what i after i believe, i am a beginner and need to more time to understand the codes

Comment: i am new this site, not sure how it works and not sure why they downvoted my questions...

Comment: I suspect it looked exceptionally unreadable in its first form. Its mildly better now that it was edited. Next question start a bit neater, don't take it too personally. Welcome and have fun with SQL.

Comment: maybe, initially my question was out of order , then i took the screenshot and reedit, now sure why the screenshot image disappeared but the code seems better than initial posting at the end, thanks

Comment: screenshots are frowned upon sometimes too, especially if they are on some external sites. if you can explain your problem with text, always use that. As you can see there is formatting that makes it readable.

Comment: @danblack,  i believe there is error in the link you provided

Comment: e.g if i record at daily basis during weekdays, no weekend, then there is a gap to calculate 5days average. @danblack?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to use an extra field for that?
You can always to calculate that data in your sql query

```
SELECT *, (open_price+closed_price)/2 as avg_price
FROM `test_price`
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question. The closed_price wasn't part of the average as the question was asked. Take a look at the answer in the comment as present this as an answer if you want.